# if link doesn't exist , try another

Tags: php

I'm searching for the fastest way to check if link is working/exist on a remote server, if not try another link. similar to "try_files" in nginx, only for links...

for example:

```
try first 
header("Location:" . $VIDEO_1);
if there's no $VIDEO_1 try
header("Location:" . $VIDEO_2);
if there's no $VIDEO_2 try
header("Location:" . $VIDEO_3);
```

currently i'm using a function that checks for size, and sends the header... but that file size check is slow

```
if($file_size > "9000000"){
        header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
        header("Location:" . $VIDEO . $dop);
}else{
        header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
        header("X-Accel-Redirect: /".$_GET["filename"].$dop);
}
```

Comment: just send a http request with javascript to see if the page exists.

Comment: [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) ?

Comment: there exists a HTTP-Head Request, like there are GET, POST,...
maybe you can use this

If you get a 200 OK reply, the request might be ok

Comment: file_exists() works only for local checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's on a remote server, you may use [get_headers()](http://php.net/get_headers):

```
$header = get_headers("http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1401975.png");
preg_match('/\d{3}/', $header[0], $code); // Extracting the HTTP status code

if($code[0] < 400){ // Or maybe just $code[0] == 200 ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    echo 'EXISTS !!!';
}else{
    echo 'Doesn\'t exists';
}
```